# safely shut down a running process by process name from command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is this even possible? I've come across all manner of techniques using `taskkill` and attempting to find the pid to shut it down, but no real answer to my question.

I'm basically trying to find the equivalent of pressing the close button in in a program, through the command line.  I just need some direction because I've reached my knowledge limit in this area.

Comment: try: `taskkill /f /im processName.exe`, if you don't want to use force, just remove `/f`.. and try to pay attention, if you run the exe with administrator privilege, then your batch file also needs an administrator privilege to execute this killing command..

Comment: updated your answer right away, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
taskkill /im processName.exe
```